# Props in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactJS and have just started learning. I am trying to get the name as props and trying to print the name but it is not working. Can someone help me with this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="app"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">
            
            class Welcome extends React.Component{
                render(){
                    return(
                        <h1> 
                            Hello {this.props.name}! 
                        </h1>
                    );
                }
            }

            class App extends React.Component{
                reder(){
                    return(
                        <div>
                            <Welcome name="Josh" />
                            <Welcome name="Captain America" />
                            <Welcome name="Peter" />
                        </div>
                    );
                }    
            }
            
            ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Open the console in your browser developer tools. Read the error message. It points pretty firmly to the fact you misspelt `render`. (Voting to close as the problem is caused by a typo).

Comment: @Quentin Good eye!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have ssyntax error i guess because you write reder instead of render in APP Class

Answer (score -1):

In App component it is written `reder`, it should be `render`.